# crypto-js versus php-mcrypt AES crypt/decrypt

Tags: cryptography, mcrypt, cryptojs

I'm trying to write a cross language crypt/decrypt tool (JavaScript vs PHP/mcryp), and I kinda got stuck.

You can find my js code http://jsbin.com/siyesaqa/31/edit here, while my php code looks like this:

```
class Manager
{

    /**
     * @param string $content
     * @param string $passphrase
     * @return string
     */
    public static function encrypt($plain, $passphrase = null) {
        $salt = mcrypt_create_iv(
            128 / 8,
            MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM
        );
        $cipher = hash_pbkdf2(
            "sha256",
            $passphrase ? $passphrase : $_ENV['SECURITY_KEY'],
            $salt,
            100,
            128 / 8
        );
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(
            mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC),
            MCRYPT_RAND
        );
        $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
            $cipher,
            $plain,
            MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
            $iv
        );
        return base64_encode($salt) . base64_encode($iv) . base64_encode($encrypted);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $encContent
     * @param string $passphrase
     * @return string
     */
    public static function decrypt($encrypted, $passphrase = null) {
        $encrypted = base64_decode($passphrase ? $passphrase : $_ENV['SECURITY_KEY']);
        $salt = substr($encrypted, 0, 128 / 8);
        $cipher = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $passphrase, $salt, 1000, 128 / 8);
        $iv = substr($encrypted, 128 / 8, 128 / 8);
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
            $cipher,
            substr($encrypted, 128 / 8 * 2),
            MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
            $iv
        ), "\0\t");
    }
}
```

As you can notice, I'm having a bit of trouble returning the same values for salt and cipher variables.

Could anyone with more experience in these two libraries give me a hint?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript encryption function hex encodes the salt and IV while the PHP function Base64 encodes them. Both functions Base64 encode the ciphertext though.

Additionally, it appears that your PHP decryption function uses 1000 rounds of PBKDF2 while all other functions use 100 rounds.

Comment: I've figured that out... I think: http://jsbin.com/siyesaqa/36/edit. My only problem now, I think, is that while php PBKDF2 returns me a 16 char string, CryptoJS returns me a 32 char string.

I'm talking ONLY about the php encrypt - CryptoJs decrypt. Once I figure these out, I'm sure I can obtain js encrypt - php decrypt as well.

Comment: @DragosCirjan When you call `toString()` on a CryptoJS Cipher object, it hex encodes the ciphertext to a string. In contrast, you are not encoding the ciphertext in PHP. It's confusing, because in PHP, strings and byte arrays are the same thing.

Comment: Sorry. My laptop died just before I updatde the php encrypt function (so I had to wait to get to a power source again). As I said... my last problem (concern) is the PBKDF2 string, which I still don't know how to make it equivalent to (from js to php or php to js).

Comment: Answered myself in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884661/crypto-js-versus-php-mcrypt-pbkdf2-differences. Giving up the idea.